# Multi-part identifier could not be bound sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to retrieve a list of rows based on three tables: `competences`, `user_competences`, `skills`. I try the following query but it says that

> The Multi-part identifier "skillmgt.timestamp" could not be bound

Query:

```
SELECT 
   Competences.*, User_Competence.e_ID
FROM 
   Competences 
INNER JOIN
   User_Competence ON User_Competence.c_ID = Competences.Competence_ID
WHERE 
   User_Competence.e_ID = 112 
   AND DATENAME(yyyy, skillmgt.timestamp) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
SELECT Competences.*, User_Competence.e_ID  
FROM Competences  
    INNER JOIN User_Competence ON User_Competence.c_ID = Competences.Competence_ID  
    INNER JOIN skillmgt SM ON User_Competence.e_ID = SM.eid  
WHERE  
    User_Competence.e_ID = 112  
    AND DATENAME(yyyy, SM.timestamp) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: I have solved it already, and the solution somewhat similar. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Your "multi-part identifier" skillmgt.timestamp isn't valid because skillmgt doesn't refer to a table or alias you're using in your query.  Did you mean to join on that table?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes; I need to retrieve the rows where the date is equal to the current's year date from that table based on the the fact that skillmgt.eid=User_Competence.e_ID